# How to change the variable of all tabs of the tabbarcontroller from first tab?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabbarcontroller

I have `@property NSString *memberid;` in `tabbarcontrller`.

I will use it in all of it's `viewcontorllers`.

I want to update the `memberid` by one of it's `viewcontroller`. so that other view controller can use the new value.

How can I update the `NSString`?

Comment: Take a look at my answer. You don't have to implement it, but at least you'll learn something ; the accepted answer is very bad practice and I suggest you step away from coding like that as soon as you understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing something like this in one of my project,

```
NSArray *tabArr = [self.tabBarController viewControllers];

UINavigationController *navController1 = [tabArr objectAtIndex:1];

DraftViewController *dvc = [navController1.viewControllers firstObject];

dvc.screenTitle = self.screenTitle;


UINavigationController *navController3 = [tabArr objectAtIndex:3];
SentViewController *svc = [navController3.viewControllers firstObject];

svc.screenTitle = self.screenTitle;

UINavigationController *navController2 = [tabArr objectAtIndex:2];
OutboxViewController *ovc = [navController2.viewControllers firstObject];

ovc.screenTitle = self.screenTitle;
```

I am doing that in my first tab (first viewcontroller of tabbarcontroller)

I have embed `navigationcontroller` to every viewcontroller (tabs). So, i get first nav controller and then get VC(tab).

If you don't have nav controller embed to your tab VC then `[tabArr objectAtIndex:index]` returns view controller directly.

Comment: Or you could have a class that handles your "members" and hence, the ID, and have that class available in all your controllers...
Some kind of "MemberService" that would be a singleton. Or even a static ! But please do not go for Lion's answer, it's terribly bad, it does not scale, it's hardcoded, it won't work when you add another tab, it's just nowhere near acceptable.

Comment: @Zil : what do you mean by add another tab? Is it like so that you are adding tab at runtime ?

Comment: No, I mean when the app must change, some day, whenever. He'll have to write more code because you're instantiating all the tab's controllers one by one to update the value. You could AT LEAST use a generic for-loop to avoid hardcoding

Comment: @Zil This is scenario that how to pass data to tabs. Then he can use for loop or anything else which is appropriate. This is the conceptual answer because he(questioner) didn't have idea about passing data to tabbar.

Answer (score 1):

Do not listen to the others here, they're just feeding you bad practice. No offense, but hardcoding stuff is just not how it works. It's not how any of this works.

A simple and easy solution could be to add a class, some kind of "Manager" or "Service". You could call it `MemberService`. This class' job is to make all the work related to your member. I don't know your app but for what you're asking, this assumption is enough. Feel free to tweak this of course.

This class could be a singleton, depending on how that `Member`works. If you have more than one you could have a list of members inside that service class, or simply a property holding the values you need.

Here, I'll go for the simplest possible, assuming one member, so you can simply have a (constant?) field holding the member ID.

Now that service just needs to be available in your controllers, where you'll ask "Hey service, what's the ID number?" and he'll reply no matter where you ask from. With that architecture, you can ask 5 times, from 20 different tabs, it'll always work. No need to mix navigation controllers and whatnot.

You UI should not be responsible for managing your logic. Controllers deal with visuals, animations, etc. All the rest should be moved in logic classes (viewmodels, services, whatever).

Now, having the same property (even a singleton) available in multiple different controllers can be a little annoying, you still have to write down the property each time. A cleaner solution than the above is subclassing your `UIViewControllers`.

Simple as that : create a ... `BaseViewController` (you can find a sexier name than that) that inherits : `UIViewController`. Add a property, your singleton service, `MemberService`, and make sure to instantiate/prepare it in the `viewDidLoad` of `BaseViewController` ; maybe you can set that member ID and other stuff there, that's your choice.

Now, all your viewcontrollers used in tabs, change their superclass (on top of the file). Instead of `: UIViewController`, use your `BaseViewController`. Tadaa, they all always have that MemberService available, and you'll 100% sure no matter how many tabs, that you have a service available, and that it is loaded and ready to kick ass (because it's been prepared in the viewdidLoad).

Answer (score 0):

// In **AppDelegate** decalre one variable for **tabcontroller** , assign your **tabcontroller** to this variable, you can **tabcontroller** in use entire app. example code is here

```
Appdelegate *appdelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

appdelegate.tabController.memberid = @"1";
```